# How to add a view between table view and navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, navigationbar

So what i m trying to achieve is I want to add a view between a tableview and the navigation bar. The hierarchy would be like:
Top-NavigationBar-betweenView-tableView-Bottom.

I have tried something like this, but the betweenView does not go under the navigation bar, and the tableView has a weird blank space above it. Anyone have any idea? Thank you!

```
    let betweenView = searchController.searchBar

    self.view.addSubview(betweenView)

    let upperConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: betweenView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.tableView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!)
    let lowerConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.tableView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: searchView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    self.view.addConstraint(upperConstraint)
    self.view.addConstraint(lowerConstraint)
```

Comment: @Essence of chicken The problem of table view header is it scrolls with the tableView, which I want the betweenView fixed on the top. I am actually using a UIViewController and dropped a table view in it already, but the constraint doesn't behave like what I want, that is what I m asking. Thank you for ur comment though!:D

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do 2 things here:

1) Layout the constraint for the search view to the top layout guide.  This will move your search view below the navigation bar on a per need basis:

```
let upperConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topLayoutGuide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
```

2) You need to make sure the table does not automatically adjust the scrolling to the navigation controller:

```
tableView.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Comment: Thank you for ur reply. I have tried your solution which I have changed the constraint's "toItem" to the topLayoutGuide, but the betweenView is still hiding after the navigation bar for some reason:( I simply don't understand why the betweenView have to stick to the very top of the screen rather than go beneath the navigation bar.

Comment: Did you make sure to use the .bottom attribute on the layout guide?  Here is a sample you can paste into a playground to see working: https://gist.github.com/pixelrevision/6482661045002868cf0ba3ad8ec264a1